SAFE Smart wallet module integration with Fireblocks
Fireblocks is aMPC Wallet that can be connected via wallet connect, but we would like to do some automations on Dexes.
As fireblocks has a high level security regarding the private key, it uses multiPartycomputational seed, not a "common" private key
​So we do not have access to a single pk string
And most dexes ask for it to work on the cloud
That is why we thought it would be a good Idea to set an smart wallet account, with one owner being an address which private key is custodied by Fireblocks and to set other private key in a safe manner (Maybe through AWS KMS) Letting the second pk to perform the trades and interact with the dexes, and the fireblocks one to suscribe and redeem

That's a great idea! What is your question?
